# Raspberry pi 4 Model B change date format

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm having a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B. How to change date format in raspberry pi from dd/mm/yyyy to dd-mm-yyyy.

[Current Raspberry Pi 4 Date Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAbSE.jpg)

Comment: are you sure you are having set the right keyboard /lanmguage first ?

Comment: @user3732793 I've set it to
Keyboard 
Model : Generic 105-key PC (intl.) 
Layout: English(US)
Variant: English(US)

Language: en(English)
Country: SG(Singapore)
Character set: UTF-8

Comment: I am farid it comes from that. Not sure if that is really changable. sorry can't help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by following this [guide](https://livingthelinuxlifestyle.wordpress.com/2020/01/07/display-the-date-and-time-using-codes-in-linux/) I'm sure you can set the date format as "dd-mm-yyyy" on your LXDE desktop eg:

```
$ date +%d-%m-%Y
08-01-2021
```